# Is it possible to have multiple has_many associations with one specific model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with the following associations:

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one  :user, as: :identifiable
    has_many :speakers
    #has_many :cast_items

end
```

**speaker.rb**

```
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :user, as: :identifiable
    #has_many :cast_items

end
```

---

As you can see, I've commented out an association with the CastItem model.
I want a Speaker to add multiple CastItems. Also, an Organization must be able to add multiple CastItems. When an Organization adds a CastItem, it does not necessarily belongs to a Speaker who is associated with an Organization. *In other words an organization must be able to add a CastItem to itself or to a Speaker who is associated with him.*

***Will it be completely valid to put the `has_many :cast_items` in both models, or are there more practical design options?***

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. Remember to add `organization_id` and `speaker_id` to your `cast_items` model.

You can check out this link, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  , some useful information regarding many to many and one to many associations.
Personally, in your case, I will use `has_many :through`

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that. I can't think of any reason that would be bad and it's often necessary.

You may want to look up the 'delegate' method for when you're creating CastItems, and have them always created by Organizations.

Also, make sure that if you have a :speaker_id on your CastItem that it can accept nil or false.